# align text box and text area at bottom id <td>

Tags: html, css

html:

```
<table>
<tr>
<td>
<div style="position: absolute; bottom:0px; ">Other <input type="text" name="otherlocation"></div>
</td>
<td>
<div>Other <input type="textarea" name="locationdescription"></div>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Text area is with height:240px and width:240px.  Now the `<td>`'s height increased to textarea's height, but I need the text input box to be aligned at the bottom of `<td>`.

The above style is not working.

Comment: FYI, there's no textarea type for input tags.  You may want to try the textarea tag instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure that I understand you correctly. But I guess you need to display the textboxes below the text "Other". If that is the case, just try this:

```
<table>
<tr>
<td>
    <div style="width:200px;height:300px; position:relative">
     <div style="position: absolute; bottom:0px;">Other <input type="text" name="otherlocation"></div>
    </div>
</td>
<td>
    <div style="width:200px;height:300px; position:relative">
        <div style="position: absolute; bottom:0px;">Other <input type="textarea" name="locationdescription"/></div>
    </div>    
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SN5Gf/2/)

Comment: ,i want to set the other and input box at bottom of <td>

Comment: The above answer is same as my question.In two <td>,textarea <td> is creating height upto 240px,but input box is at the top of the <td>.I want it to align at the bottom of <td>.

Comment: @Monk L: I'm not sure if i understand your requirement correctly one more time. Check my updated answer